# CanJS folder structure

Tags: javascript, canjs, application-structure

When  creating simple projects we directly specify models and controllers in the same file and then write. My app.js looks like this:

```
var Library = can.Model({});   
var Control = can.Control({.....});    
var control = new Control('#main');
```

and single html file for this

For complex applications i will have different folders for controllers, models and views.
My first question is

1 How will the invocation will take place when I place the controllers in different folder and the Modules in different folders. Can some one help me with a template of a base file which will invoke all the controllers.

1.If I have a simple html file for a specific controller instead of an ejs will it work?

I know it might sound stupid to some extend but I am confused.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [CanJS + RequireJS TodoMVC example](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/labs/dependency-examples/canjs_require). This should demonstrate everything you need to get started with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) using the AMD module version of CanJS.

And of course you can instantiate your control in an HTML file without having to use EJS (or Mustache) views.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a tool like require.js, your code will look something like this:

```
define(['control' ], function(Control){ 
    var control = new Control('#id');       
});
```

Or use namespaces:

```
// user_control.js
APP.controllers = APP.controllers || {};
APP.controllers.UserControl = can.Control({...

// other file
var control = APP.controllers.UserControl('#id');
```

Answer (score 0):

To instantiate an html instead of ejs we can use

```
this.view({
            url: 'views/demos/accordion.html'
        });
```

Might be useful for some one else.